# Table name in another table using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I have one table in which I have name of all the tables. 
Table

```
ID   | Name | table_name|
1    |   A  |      abc
2    |   B  |      xyz
3    |   C  |      123
```

Now I have tables abc, xyz and 123 on the basis of name I want to get the table name and then from that table I want it complete data

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT table_name FROM Table 1 WHERE Table1.Name = 'A')
```

This query is not working in PostgreSQL

Comment: That query won't work in *any* database. You will need to create a function that uses dynamic SQL in order to achieve this. See here for examples: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN or here: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions

Comment: do what a_horse_with_no_name said and read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score -2):

Please try after modifying the query as follows:

SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT table_name FROM Table 1 WHERE Table1.Name = 'A') As TblName

Comment: this returns table_name as the result.